# Access to api data working in react but not react/redux, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm new to react and practicing using it with api data. I have a version of a simple app i'm making that pulls data from an exchange rates api (https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=GBP) and displays the data on the screen (as a first step) - github link here: (https://github.com/char502/Exchange_App_NoRedux). I am able to access the relevant part of the returned object by using the following code (lines 82 to 85 on the 'components/RequestExchange.js' page):

```
{Object.keys(items.rates).map((key, index) => (
              <li key={index}>
                {key}: {items.rates[key]}
              </li>
```

I am also building the same project with redux to help my currently weak redux skills:
(https://github.com/char502/exchange_rate_app_react) however, when i try to access the same part of the api as the above example (without redux), i cannot get the data to output to console or render to screen. I just keep getting the error 'TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object'. I can get the first level of data to the screen (i.e. base rate, line 79 in the redux version of the app) so i know the data is coming through, i just don't understand why i can't access the data a layer below (a nested object of key/value pairs showing country code and the rates themselves) when i believe i'm applying the right way to access it (as the code above works in the non-redux version). I would be grateful if someone  could check my code and see what is going on, is it some asynchronous thing i'm missing or is the data not flowing through redux correctly, i just can't tell and I've been struggling with this for days.

Apologies for long post i'm just trying to provide all context in the hope that the problem is easy to spot by someone who knows what they're doing?

Comment: Can you tell at what line are you facing this error?

Comment: Hi, when i uncomment lines 83-89 in the file: 'ExchangeRateList.js' in the non-working redux version (https://github.com/char502/exchange_rate_app_react) i get the error 'TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object' even though the exact same code used in the non-redux version works

Comment: SOLVED - this has now been solved, it would appear that i was trying to render to screen before the data had fully loaded. I had the following logic in my render method:


render() {
    const { error, loading, items } = this.props;

    if (error) {
      return <div>Error! {error.message}</div>;
    }

    if (loading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

But i needed to include '|| !items.rates' in the render condition so the component would not render until the nested object was available

Comment: Good that you found the solution on your own.